# Google Maps idle event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing some experimentation with Google maps, and my aim is to place markers on a map which will depend on when it is dragged or resized, so I'm planning to use the "idle" event listener. The problem is that I can't get it to work.

I've put an alert box inside the idle listener to test it, but it doesn't get fired. 
This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>

var map;
    var geocoder;
    var markers = [];

function initialize() 
{   
        var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    //regenerateMarkers(); // 29/7/15
}




// Initializes the Google Map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

    //regenerateMarkers(); // 29/7/15

    alert("inside idle");

});

</script>
```

The html to display the map is as follows:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 450px; width: 900px;"></div>
```

I cannot for the life of me see why the idle listener is not firing to bring up the alert box. Can anyone please help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should bind `idle` event inside `initialize` function otherwise map couldn't be already loaded and event can't be bound.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! 
Can I ask another question please? The alert box displays before the map has finished rendering (its just a grey window); is it possible to display my markers while the map is just blank? (Sorry, I am new to all this :)

Comment: inside `idle` event handler you can load your markers and display them in the map without problems

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!